# How can i insert iframe in footer Layout Zend without refresh this footer?

Tags: zend-framework, footer

I am building an application using Zend Framework and i need insert one iframe in footer this application but, when i press F5 or click link or button, all page refresh even iframe.
The layout zend is called everytime when i dispatcher an event to server, ready, the iframe too. (My iframe is in the foorter.phtml, ready, it called together layout).

Someone have an some idea how to resolve this question?

tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refresh the whole page except for an `iframe` on the page. When you ask a browser to refresh a page, it will refresh the whole page, there's no way to do it any differently.

To do what you seem to want to do, without using Javascript/AJAX, you'd have to use two frames. One for the top part of your website, and one for your footer. Here is an introduction to `frames` and how they work (`iframes` are similar, they are just "internal frames"): http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html

Please, however, note that using `frames`/`iframes` is not a practice I personally encourage.  You should ask yourself why you are trying to do this. If it's to reload only a certain part of the page, then you should probably check into Javascript/AJAX alternatives.

Comment: Ok @mbinette, i'll see the contents of the link and returno.

Comment: Ok @mbinette, i'll see the contents of the link and return.
The for the record, Javascript/Ajax in my application is very hard and impossible becouse i would have that to rebuild all the my application. I am trying to build a interactive register, like a "next->next->finish". My interactive bar is in my footer, it should stay there, next, it can't refresh... =(, the Zend Layout refresh everytime all the pages in my application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the layout for some action you can use `$this->_helper->layout ()->disableLayout ();`. Put it in the iframe action, which will disable the layout and will show only the view of the action.